# How do I add child nodes to elements with the same name using LINQ to XML?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

My problem I have with elements at the same level that have the same name, is that when I go to insert the next sub elements it always defaults to insert it to the first one that I created.

So for example

Say I want to create xml that looks like this

```
<Parent>

<Brother>
</Brother>

<Sister>
    <child1>
    </child1>
    <child2>
    </child2>
</Sister>
<Sister>

    <child1>
    </child1>
    <child2>
    </child2>

 </Sister>
 <Sister>
 </Sister>

</Parent>
```

I first insert all the Child nodes into first Sister element, then create next sister element which is fine (new Sister element tag appears in string. But when I try to insert the child nodes to the second 'Sister' element using this

```
doc.Element("Parent").Element("Sister").Add(new XElement("Child1", "value"));
```

It just puts it into the first element that I created

How do I tell it to insert to the second Sister element not the first, or not to the ones I already visited?

What is a good way to handle this?

Comment: `doc.Element("Parent").Elements("Sister").Skip(1).First().Add(new XElement("Child1", "value"));`

Comment: Try using the Last() method instead. So `doc.Element("Parent").Elements("Sister").Last().Add(new XElement("Child1", "value"));`